# FragmentActivity class for below api level 11 devices

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity, android-api-levels

I am new to android development.

I created class and extend that class from `FragmentActivity`.

When I use this function `getFragmentManager()`

it does not allow me to do it

I am also unable to use `getSupportFragmentManager` because its also giving me error that can not convert from support api to android.app

But then I used TargetApi(11) attribute on my abstract class that I extend from `FragmentActivity` class.

Now the error is gone.

But I like to know, does targetApi(11) limits my app from running my app on adroid devices below api 11?

Or below api 11 does not allow fragmment or hence does not support FragmentActivity class ?

If last thing that i mention is true,  should I instead of fragment should I use new activities?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? Did you add `appcompat`/`support` library to your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TargetApi(11)** only suppress lint warning, you app can still run below 11. however if may crash if API is not available in lower Android platform.

The correct way to solve your issue is use Android support library, it include *FragmentActivity* in package *android.support.v4.app*.

You need edit you gradle file to include android support library

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

Then sync gradle file and recompile your project.

Answer (score 1):

Don't import android.app.FragmentActivity.
It need api larger than android 3.0.
You can import android.support.v4.app,FragmentActivity!!
And you problem is solved!